# SimpleHTMLDOM - Exclude element inside div

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using SimpleHTMLDOM and trying to get some content from a site. And I must say that im very happy with using SimpleHTMLDOM, but I can't find anything on my problem and how to solve it.

The goes like this:
I'm trying to extract the string from a follow element: foo.

This is the markup for element foo on the site:

```
<div class="foo"> 
   Lorem Ipsum 
   <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

And the php code i'm using is like this:

```
foreach($html->find('.foo ') as $m)
        $foo = $m->innertext;
```

This will output:

```
Lorem Ipsum <div class="bar"></div>
```

So my question is how to exclude the div/element inside the class foo?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does `with` come from ? I guess it's inside the `div.bar`... correct your question please...

Comment: Woops, didnt notice before now. But I have updated my question, it was supposed to be 'Lorem Ipsum with <div class="bar"></div>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find the first text node with something similar to the following...

```php
foreach($html->find('.foo') as $foo)
    echo $foo->find('text', 0);
```

Comment: not a problem - it's worth looking into [*php: dom*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) though if you're doing anything on a large scale as it's way faster.

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks for the tip.